# ubuntu software center crashes on launch

Tags: software-center

When I select the software center icon from launcher and enter the login, software center makes an attempt at launching but then crashes. I am a linux noob and not very linux-literate. I also have a red dot with a white horizonal line going through it at the top of my screen, next to the time and date.

Comment: You need to install updates.

Comment: Hi celticwarrior, how do i install updates?

Comment: i changed the server and that allowed me to download the updates. thanx